# Grunt: automatically creating CSS selectors based on HTML

Tags: css, gruntjs

I'm new to Grunt. Is there a way of automatically appending CSS selectors based on what HTML I input?

For example, if I input this into my HTML file -

```
<div class="myDiv"></div>
```

for grunt for then to automatically append this to my CSS file -

```
.myDiv {
}
```

If such a thing existed it would be a great time saver.

Comment: check the docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-css-selectors

Comment: Thanks but as far as I can tell that doesn't do what I need it to do.